# Update Word document with Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I am trying to update a Word document using Excel VBA.  Found this code at the link below but it is not working for me.

It steps through the code but the Word document is not updated.  At this point, all I am trying to do is insert today's date on the letter.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strValue As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CustomerNames")
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\kindyd1\Desktop\COPE\receipt_letter.docx"

    objWord.Activate

    With objWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "<<DateToday>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

[Link to similar exercise](https://superuser.com/questions/1317223/replace-word-in-ms-word-with-cell-value-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Does the text '<<DateToday>>' actually exist in the opened document?

Comment: Yes.  In fact it actually exists in a couple spots and I have double checked to make sure that the formatting is the same in all locations.

Comment: And you are using Early Binding with a Project > Reference to Microsoft Word? If not, change wdReplaceAll to a value of 2.

Comment: Early and Late Binding...that is a new one.  I did replace the test as recommended and it partially worked.  It replaced a single existence but did not replace the other.  It is progress none the less. Thank you

Comment: The replacing of only a single instance has something to do do with the fact that the other instance is inside a shape that has the text inside of it.  Any thoughts on how I reference the text inside the shape?   When you do a Word search it works fine.  It is just when you do the VBA word search that it only captures the single instance and not what is in the shape.

Comment: To help you with the text inside of a shape, you will have to explain more about the shape and even post a picture. Add these things to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information you supplied in Comments above, the answer to at least part of the problem you are having with the VBA code you are using involves Late Binding. Your code references a Word setting `wdReplaceAll` that is not available if your solution uses Late Binding.

The issue can be resolved by either adding a Project Reference to Microsoft Word, which then changes your automation binding to Early Binding and then `wdReplaceAll` can be understood correctly by your Excel based macro, or ... to use the absolute value that `wdReplaceAll` represents, which is a value of 2.

Here is a article for you to read regarding Early vs Late Binding:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation